# Tomcat stops running when I exit the Terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat

I am trying to run Tomcat on Ubuntu System from a remote host. However, when I exit the terminal, Tomcat process shuts down.

The command I am using to run it is

```
nohup ./startup.sh &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start tomcat with its startup script:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat5 start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7 and trying to start tomcat from the tomcat/bin folder

Comment: what about using `/etc/init.d/tomcat7`?